# iPod Shuffle like device for Deezer

Tags: music

I am searching the internet for a iPod Shuffle like device to listen Deezer music (iPod Shuffle was *offline* device). 
I would like to somehow download or use device within Wifi or Bluetooth range. 
It needs to use headphones for listening.

Deezer is limited to specific devices. However I would like to have look and feel experience of iPod Shuffle.

Is there any solution available or similar look&feel to iPod Shuffle?